# How to have a page display all relationships in Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How can I have one resource view display data for all relationships in the view all resource page (and hopefully still be sortable and searchable)?

For example, I have 2 tables:

Vendor - id, vendor_name
Product - id, product_name, year

I want to have a view to display the table:

Vendor ID | Vendor Name | Product ID | Product Name | Year

Currently, I have one page for the vendor and one page for products.  I want to combine the results into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your table structure and your demand, I suggest this solution:

```
// database\migrations\2019_10_04_153155_create_vendors_table.php
        Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
// database\migrations\2019_10_04_153325_create_products_table.php
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
// database\migrations\2019_10_04_154713_create_product_vendor_table.php
        Schema::create('product_vendor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('product_id');
            $table->bigInteger('vendor_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
// app\Product.php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function vendors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class,'product_vendor');
    }
}
// app\Vendor.php
class Vendor extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'product_vendor');
    }
}
// app\ProductVendor.php
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \App\Product;
use \App\Vendor;
class ProductVendor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_vendor';
    public function GetColumnProductNameAttribute()
    {
        if($this->product_id){
            return Product::find($this->product_id)->name;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
    public function GetColumnVendorNameAttribute()
    {
        if($this->vendor_id){
            return Vendor::find($this->vendor_id)->name;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
    public function GetColumnProductYearAttribute()
    {
        if($this->product_id){
            return Product::find($this->product_id)->year;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}
// app\Nova\Product.php
    public static $title = 'name';
// app\Nova\Vendor.php
    public static $title = 'name';
// app\Nova\ProductVendor.php
<?php
namespace App\Nova;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Number;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
class ProductVendor extends Resource
{
    public static $model = 'App\ProductVendor';
    public static $title = 'id';
    public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->join('vendors', 'product_vendor.vendor_id', '=', 'vendors.id')
        ->join('products', 'product_vendor.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('vendors.name as column_vendor_name','products.name as column_product_name','products.year as column_product_year','product_vendor.*','products.*','vendors.*');
    }
    public static $search = [
        'id','products.name','vendors.name'
    ];
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            ID::make('Vendor Id','vendor_id')
                ->sortable(),
            Text::make('Vendor Name','column_vendor_name')
                ->sortable()
                ->hideWhenCreating(),
            ID::make('Product Id','product_id')
                ->sortable(),
            Text::make('Product Name','column_product_name')
                ->sortable()
                ->hideWhenCreating(),
            Text::make('Product Year','column_product_year')
                ->sortable()

        ];
    }
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

[image]
The main idea is show pivot table product_vendor join with 2 table: products, and vendors. Then with some basic command setup, you will be able to search product name, vendor name (or more), and sortable (all). Good luck, and ask me if you need!

UPDATE:

For fix the error on sortable and searching id, need change a bit in the ProductVendor Nova:

```
// indexQuery:
    public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->join('vendors', 'product_vendor.vendor_id', '=', 'vendors.id')
        ->join('products', 'product_vendor.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('product_vendor.id as temp_id','products.id as temp_product_id','vendors.id as temp_vendor_id','vendors.name as column_vendor_name','products.name as column_product_name','products.year as column_product_year','product_vendor.*','products.*','vendors.*');
    }
// $search
    public static $search = [
        'product_vendor.id','products.name','vendors.name'
    ];
// fields function
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make('ID','temp_id')->sortable(),
            ID::make('Vendor Id','vendor_id')
                ->sortable(),
            Text::make('Vendor Name','column_vendor_name')
                ->sortable()
                ->hideWhenCreating(),
            ID::make('Product Id','product_id')
                ->sortable(),
            Text::make('Product Name','column_product_name')
                ->sortable()
                ->hideWhenCreating(),
            Text::make('Product Year','column_product_year')
                ->sortable()

        ];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually moved off of Nova but this would have worked.